# How to print lines of list without square brackets and commas?

Tags: python, list

So I have this problem where the program prints the lines of a list with the square brackets and commas.

```
lista=[]
f=open("eloadas.txt", "r")
for sor in f:
    sor=sor.strip().split()
    lista.append(sor)
lista.sort()
print("\n".join(map(str, lista)))
```

This is what I tried and the expected thing to happen was this:

```
1 1 32 Kovacs Lajos
1 10 30 Bolcskei Zsuzsanna
1 2 43 Kiss Peter
```

But instead of that, I got this:

```
['1', '1', '32', 'Kovacs', 'Lajos']
['1', '10', '30', 'Bolcskei', 'Zsuzsanna']
['1', '2', '43', 'Kiss', 'Peter']
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Just like you use `"\n".join` to turn `lista` into a single string, you need use `" ".join` to turn each list *in* `lista` into a string, not simply call `str` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `str` on each inner map, you could join it with a space:

```py
print("\n".join(map(lambda l : " ".join(l), lista)))
```

Answer (score 0):

python has something called an "unpacking operator" - when used on a list, it will act as if the brackets are not there.

say `x = [1, 2, 3]`, `*x` will be as if I wrote `1, 2, 3`.

print can have arguments separated by commas.

these two features can be used together to get:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(*x)
1 2 3 4
```

if you want to print a list with no commas, use `print(*listname)`

this might go something like:

```
lista=[]
f=open("eloadas.txt", "r")
for sor in f:
    sor=sor.strip().split()
    lista.append(sor)
lista.sort()

for item in lista:
    print(*item)
```

but this is not the most efficient...